# How to write an client-server video streaming

Tags: c#, .net, video, streaming, rtp

I'm working on project that will work real time: I have to write a video streaming client-server app, this server will to send the AVI/MPEG etc to an web application. I have some questions:

1. What is the protocol recommend to do this, http? rtp? or other?
2. In the web application, how do I to show it to user? using an flash player,java applet(I don't ensure if it's possible with it) or HTML5, what is the best way to do this currently?

I hope this is clean for you. Any help is very appreciadted. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: check Microsoft Smooth Streaming at http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2009/apr09/04-20SmoothStreamingPR.mspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different ways to implement this (some that require programming and others that don't). Which one you choose depends on your requirements.

[Red5](http://www.red5.org/) is an obvious solution which will allow you to only have to focus on the web side as long as your player of choice is flash.

[FlourineFx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) provides a similar environment for .NET with a little more effort.

I've also done this with IIS and a custom server using `HttpListener` with much success if you're set on a pure Windows/C# solution. The caveat I'd add here is that it isn't always simple. In an environment with limited throughput, you will have problems since HTTP doesn't have the time corrections that RTP/RTMP/RTSP have but in a decent network it works 3 9's of the time (I've only tested with a single player though).

UPDATE

If you're talking about *live* streaming with .NET I'd suggest looking into the DirectShow (or related DirectX) API's. There is a wrapper for it for .NET available called [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. that you wrote using IIS and HttpListener get it from an device(like webCam or equivalent to) in real time?

Comment: Forgive me for trying to clarify (your comment isn't very clear), are you saying you're trying to find a solution that can stream from a webcam or similar? If so, that requirement is significantly different than what you've asked in your question above. I'd probably look into using DirectShow (or one of the more recent DirectX libraries) to help you with that. Doing so is not a minor task though.

Comment: It exactly what you said. Maybe I used wrong words in this topic. But I'II accept you answer and look for DirectShow. if you have an information about DirectShow usage, link for me please. :)

Comment: Realtime can mean something different from *live*. I've updated my answer with a link to a .NET wrapper for DirectShow.