# How to stream a video file from my server to client in c#

Tags: c#, video

I was able to send image from server to client . there is two image when one comes after another it display like a video, but now i want to stream a video from my client to server. I want to stream the file from my own localhost.

## Sending

```
 private void Start_Sending_Video_Conference(string remote_IP, int port_number)
        {
            try
            {

                ms = new MemoryStream();// Store it in Binary Array as Stream


                IDataObject data;
                Image bmap;

                //  Copy image to clipboard
                SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0);

                //  Get image from clipboard and convert it to a bitmap
                data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap)))
                {
                    bmap = ((Image)(data.GetData(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap))));
                    bmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                }

                
                picCapture.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] arrImage = ms.GetBuffer();
                myclient = new TcpClient(remote_IP, port_number);//Connecting with server
                myns = myclient.GetStream();
                mysw = new BinaryWriter(myns);
                mysw.Write(arrImage);//send the stream to above address
                ms.Flush();
                mysw.Flush();
                myns.Flush();
                ms.Close();
                mysw.Close();
                myns.Close();
                myclient.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Video Conference Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

## Receiving

```
private void Start_Receiving_Video_Conference()
        {
            try
            {

                // Open The Port
                mytcpl = new TcpListener(6000);
                mytcpl.Start();                      // Start Listening on That Port
                mysocket = mytcpl.AcceptSocket();        // Accept Any Request From Client and Start a Session
                ns = new NetworkStream(mysocket);    // Receives The Binary Data From Port

                picture_comming.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);
                mytcpl.Stop();                           // Close TCP Session

                if (mysocket.Connected == true)          // Looping While Connected to Receive Another Message 
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Start_Receiving_Video_Conference();              // Back to First Method
                    }
                }
                myns.Flush();

            }
            catch (Exception) { button1.Enabled = true; myth.Abort(); }
        }
```

so how should i stream a video file in my client end where the file is in my server.

Comment: Have you tried this link? http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146770/how-to-write-an-client-server-video-streaming

Comment: but that is web api and i am using udp socket....... @gypsyCoder